# All customer Page is not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer

I cannot open `All customer` from `Magento` Backend.No log file is generated.Primarily I thought it would be due to some module So I disable all the 3rd party module.But still it does not open.I got this...
[image]
I need help in this regard.Please help.

Comment: please enable error reporting from app/bootstrap.php uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1); then see what is error in browser

Comment: Clear cache and cookies of your browser and check!

Comment: @AnsarHusain I did it and now it shows error.Thank you:)